# Why is my model all triangulated and messed up on export to .FBX and .OBJ?

Tags: mesh, export, wireframe

So I faced this problem when exporting a simple chair model that I modelled in Blender, to FBX and OBJ (Haven't tried other formats yet), here it is in Blender preview.

[image: All good here1]

[image]

The Base is quite low poly and the cushion is high poly as it is a cloth modified and subdivided mesh.

As you can see here, nothing seems wrong whatsoever but when I export it and open in a 3D viewing software : [image]

[image]

It appears the edges have formed tris in a very weird way, I tried Merge by Distance but it didn't help. I tried opening the file in other software as well, no luck. What is this and how can I fix it?

Comment: Hi, what format are you exporting to? Please [edit] your question and add more information.

Comment: Are you using any modifiers on the object?

Comment: Looks like the ngons in back of chair are causing grief. Try fixing the back to match the legs (all quads).

Comment: @susu I used Mirror Modifier on the chair base, but they all have been applied before export.

Comment: @Timaroberts FBX and OBJ

Comment: @batFINGER Ok, I will try that, thank you

Comment: @batFINGER thanks, it worked! I converted the n gons to tris, and then to quads. The topology now is quite bad but atleast it worked!

Comment: please consider posting an answer.

Comment: So I found out the problem, I had a lot of N Gons (Faces made out of more than 4 vertices). These N Gons were specifically in the back of the chair, hence the results on export. To fix this, go into edit mode, deselect any of your mesh, F3 and search for Select Faces by side and click on that function, then in the bottom left menu set the Method to 'Greater Than' and the number to 4. This will show you the faces that have more than 4 vertices. Then with those faces selected by the above function, search 'Triangulate faces'. This will divide all the faces to triangles. Now search and click.

Comment: Follow up to the last answer, now search and click to quads. This will promptly convert all the triangles to quadrilaterals. Now recheck if there are any n gons in the scene by redoing the steps mentioned above. This solved the problem upon export, hope it solves your one too.